# Why is multiple inheritance of interfaces a much less difficult thing to achieve than multiple inheritance from a set of classes?

Tags: inheritance, interface

Why is multiple inheritance of interfaces a much less difficult thing to achieve than multiple inheritance from a set of classes?
I am stuck on a university question.
Thanks

Comment: Easier for whom? The language designer? The compiler writer? The programmer using the language?

Comment: multiple class inheritance is not just more difficult, its impossible for a java programmer.

Comment: sorry, ignore my "java" tag. I meant languages in general. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inherit two methods with the same signature from different classes, you have an ambiguity when calling this method. It can be resolved, but it is arguably a messy situation.

If you implement two interfaces with the same method signature, it doesn't matter, because there's still just one implementation to choose from when calling the method.

[The diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) is an extension of the problem described above, which makes the situation even messier. This problem basically goes away when restricting multiple inheritance to interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because of granularity: you can pick which interfaces should your class implement. Whereas if you extend a class, you automatically inherit the whole hierarchy of classes.

Comment: But you automatically get the whole hierarchy of interfaces when implementing interfaces.

Comment: True, but they are only signatures :P

Comment: Yup. But your answer is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:
1.) the diamond problem (look in Wikipedia for that),
2.) object identity.

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C : A, B { }

C * c = new C ();
A * a = c;
B * b = c;
```

Then you cannot verify object identity by simply testing a == b. If you try to implement this feature in a language, you cannot use simple pointer arithmetic in the background, such that *every* access to a class (independently from muliple inheritance) gets much more costly, since a and b are not ordinary pointers anymore.

If A and B are interfaces, you know about the problem (you know that they will be inherited), such that you can treat access to interfaces differently from access to classes.

By the way: Multiple class inheritance is not *that* difficult to achieve.

Edit: Addition. And it introduces conceptual problems:

```
class C0 { virtual int meth { return 0; } };
class C1 : C0 { virtual int meth { return 1; } };
class C2 : C1, C0 { }
```

If we define

```
C2 * c2 = new C2;
```

What should

```
((C1 *) c2)->meth()
```

and

```
((C0 *) c2)->meth()
```

return in order not to confuse people? (Edit: Corrected this example.)

Comment: With regard to your latter question, I see no ambiguity; the first call should return 1, and the latter call 0.  A problem comes if two classes `C1a` and `C1b` inherit a common base class `C0` and override the same virtual member `f`, and another class `C2` inherits from both of those.  If upcasts had to be performed a level at a time (e.g. given `C2 it`, one couldn't just say `(C0)it` but would have to say `(C0)(C1a)it` or `(C0)(C1b)it`) that would resolve the ambiguity, but `(C0)(C1a)it` and `(C0)(C1b)it` would behave either like objects of different types, or as distinct objects.

Comment: Sorry, my example was set up to sloppily (no pointers). I do, however, see conceptual problems, as you can argue both for `(C0 *) c2->meth ()` returning 0 (since `C2` directly inherits from `C0`, `C2` does not define `meth`, and it is not clear why a `class C2 : C1, C0` should be different from a `class C2 : C0` when converted to `C0`, or you could argue for 1 (since `(C0*)(C1*)c2` should not be different from `(C0*)c2`).

Comment: If a language freely supports multiple inheritance, I can't see any way to maintain the identity that `(TFinalType)(TIntermediate1)thing` will be equivalent to `(TFinalType)(TIntermediate2)thing` in all cases where both expressions are well-formed and use only upcasts or self-casts.  Consequently, I can't see any way of avoiding a requirement that a value of a multiply-inheriting class type only be upcast to its immediate supertype, and that an upcast must be regarded as "direct".  Since C0 is a direct supertype of C2, the cast should be regarded as not going via C1.

Answer (score 0):

As noted at least in .net, interface methods are only available on objects which are declared to be of, or constrained to, interface types.  Consequently, if a `C1` has method `Foo`, and also implements interfaces `Intf1` and `Intf2`, each of which declares a method `Foo`, then in most cases the fact that there exist three methods named `Foo` won't matter since they'll exist in what are essentially separate domains.

Further, if an interface `IDerived1` and `IDerived2` inherit `IBase`, which includes member `Foo`, a class which implements both interfaces, or an interface which inherits both interfaces, will just define one definition of `IBase.Foo`.  It would be possible for `IDerived1`, `IDerived2`, and/or an interface deriving from both to declare their own `Foo` members, but any such definitions would be completely separate from `IBase.Foo`.  Casting a derived interface to `IBase` and calling `Foo` on it will always yield the same `IBase.Foo` method, regardless of whether one casts directly to `IBase`, or one casts to other interfaces first.  By contrast, if a class derives from two other classes, both of which override the same member of a common base class, it's unclear what should happen if one casts an object of the derived class to the base class and then tries to use that member.

Incidentally, there is are a couple situation where ambiguities can arise.  If an interface inherits two interfaces that have members of the same name, it may be necessary to use some tricks to force the compiler to favor one over the other, or to have the derived interface add its own member of the same name which would shadow both of the originals.  Also, when using generics, it's possible to constrain a generic type to implement multiple interfaces and also inherit from a class.  When this is done, there is a possibility of ambiguity if the interfaces and/or the class share member names.